# angular template function call

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to call the convert function in an angulat template like covert{{item.size}} ? if it is possible what is the correct syntax? Thanks.

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md [matTooltip]="item.size">
                                            <span *ngIf="!item.isFolder">covert{{item.size}}</span>
                                        </mat-cell>
```

#code converter

```
 convert(x){
    const units = ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
     let l = 0, n = parseInt(x, 10) || 0;
     while(n >= 1024 && ++l){
         n = n/1024;
     }
     return(n.toFixed(n < 10 && l > 0 ? 1 : 0) + ' ' + units[l]);
   }
```

Comment: Hey @Tim Launders ! Please check the given solutions (it should work). And add a `console.log('called'); into the `convert` method. Tell me how log are you getting ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides a way to achieve this via pipes. You can create one pipe and put you conversion logic there. It is a good choice because if you need anywhere else in you application it can be easily consumed binding such logic to component function is not a good idea.

Create pipe using `angular cli` or just by creating pipe and its spec.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'convert'})
export class convert implements PipeTransform {
  transform(x: number): number {
   const units = ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
     let l = 0, n = parseInt(x, 10) || 0;
     while(n >= 1024 && ++l){
         n = n/1024;
     }
     return(n.toFixed(n < 10 && l > 0 ? 1 : 0) + ' ' + units[l]);
  }
}
```

I haven't changed any logic for the conversion as I assume it is not having any issues. Now, you can use this pipe in your component like this:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md [matTooltip]="item.size">
        <span *ngIf="!item.isFolder">{{item.size | convert}}</span>
</mat-cell>
```

Comment: @Apoorva , how do we call or make the pipe global ? so that I can call it in all components?

Comment: Yes, it is always good to keep the logic outside the component as adding such things in it makes them complex for rendering and do more computation.

Comment: shall I call that as a service ? , for example I wanna use that on my DocumentComponent , how do I call that globally?

Comment: You can use `ng g pipe 'name of the pipe'`. it will be added to the nearest module. If you are using multiple module try to add it to the specific one as of now later on you can move to root if needed.

Comment: and how to call a pipe ? on a component?

Comment: When you import this pipe in the module it will be detected automatically in the component.No need to add it explicitly to the component. Try adding it to the root module now.

Comment: how to call a pipe on another component Sir after the pipe is created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235132/discussion-between-apoorva-chikara-and-tim-launders).

Comment: check [this](https://www.angularjswiki.com/pipes/custompipe/) link.

Comment: No pipe found with name 'convert'.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
{{ convert(item.size) }} or <span>convert(item.size)</span>
```